# Zend2 on WAMP not working correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework2, wamp

Im in the following situation: 
I installed WAMP, then I installed the zend framework 2 skeleton application.
I enabled mod_rewrite for apache, but when I browse to  localhost\myapplication, it shows me the index of page with the list of folders for the root. When I click on the public folder I can see the page from zend2 successfully.

Now I created a new module as shown in the tutorial on the ZF2 website. He just goes to  http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album and says it should show an website.
If I browse to localhost/album I get tje message `The requested URL /Zend/public/album was not found on this server.`

I think I've got a problem with the setup of WAMP in combination with zend framework, because I see the index of page with the folder listing and need to click on it to get to the index page.

Is it even possible to get ZF2 working without a virtual host on WAMP?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html#using-the-apache-web-server)? You need set up a virtual host (with the root set as the `public` directory) and also add a entry to you `hosts` file

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, you just need to change the structure of the files if you don't want to edit your apache configuration.

Take all the files from the `public` folder, and put them in your wamp `www` folder (`c:\wamp\www`).

Then make sure the other zf2 files (`config`, `data`, `module` etc) are in `c:\wamp`.  Now you should be able to access your application at `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/album`

Comment: So it is not possible to let the structure be as it is ? i mean like c:\wamp\public\....  and rewrite it with .htaccess ?

Comment: To do that edit `httpd.conf` file so document_root points to public and not www.

Comment: Thanks that did the job for directly showing the public index page.

Comment: But i still have the problem that i cannot access the album page (localhost/album), its shows me that The requested URL /album/index was not found on this server. without anything of zend

Comment: Most likely .htaccess file is not taking effect.  Make sure AllowOverride All is set for your virtual host.